# How can I install the M2E - Maven Integration in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am attempting to install the plugin via the repository install in Eclipse ( Help -> Install New Software -> Work With: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/ -> Next) and am getting a big error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse (includes Incubating components) 1.6.2.20150902-0002 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.6.2.20150902-0002)
  Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.6.0.20150526-2032 (org.eclipse.m2e.core 1.6.0.20150526-2032) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.core.resources 3.9.0' but it could not be found
  Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.6.1.20150625-2338 (org.eclipse.m2e.core 1.6.1.20150625-2338) requires 'bundle com.google.guava [14.0.1,16.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.6.2.20150902-0002 (org.eclipse.m2e.core 1.6.2.20150902-0002) requires 'bundle com.google.guava [14.0.1,16.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: m2e Marketplace 1.6.2.20150902-0002 (org.eclipse.m2e.discovery 1.6.2.20150902-0002)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core [1.6.0,1.7.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse (includes Incubating components) 1.6.2.20150902-0002 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.6.2.20150902-0002)
    To: org.eclipse.m2e.discovery [1.6.2.20150902-0002]
```

I tried finding information on the guava bundle but am not able to search for this in the Eclipse marketplace or find any repo out there I can install from either.

I am using Eclipse Juno SR2.  I've read that certain version of Eclipse can't install guava bundle but didn't read that Juno was one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Juno only supports 1.3 version. So download it from here.

[download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3](http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to install the latest version of **m2e** into a *very* old version of Eclipse; the two are not compatible. You have 2 options:

1. [Install a new version of Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/). The Java and Java EE packages both include **m2e** so you won't have to do anything to install it into them. Plus you get the benefit of having the latest features and bug fixes in both Eclipse and m2e.
2. Install the version of m2e that's compatible with your Juno Eclipse release. To do so with the Install New Software... wizard, select the Juno repository to work with (*not* the m2e repository), and search for m2e in the list of options.